# SSRS Matrix row groups as actual rows

Tags: reporting-services

I'm not sure how to explain this, and i've tried a lot of different options, but what i want is this.

I want a matrix row group to show up as actual rows, not as columns, in the lay-out.

So, if i make a matrix with a column group of resources, and 2 row groups: project group and project name, those 2 should not be in seperate columns. I just want to make the group bold, and the projects in the same column, below it.

This is just an example, my real problem is that when adding a lot of row groups, the report becomes too wide.

How i would like it:

```
         |  resource1  |  resource2  |  resource3
group1   |
project1 |
project2 |
group2   |
project3 |
project4 |
```

What it's right now:

```
                    |  resource1  |  resource2  |  resource3
Group1  |  project1 |
        |  project2 |
Group2  |  project3 |
        |  project4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Put Projects in Detail Row. Add a parent group for your "Group" data. Add a Group Total Above to details row. In my case Dimension2DetailAkro is your Group data and Dimension1DetailAkro is your "project" group:

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_JVKkux5oAjM/Sifa2RBMKgI/AAAAAAAAJNo/Tf8jXkvbcio/s1600-h/GroupingExample.gif

Hope this helps

Cheers

Markus

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement to break out the projects in each group into separate rows defeats the grouping.

Each matrix row (grouping) is discrete. You need to separate the project and group data and have them treated as discrete matrix rows.

One way (possibly the only way) is to make the dataset return data this way.

In rough terms:

```
SELECT group data, GroupID + '1111' AS DummySorting
UNION ALL
SELECT project data, GroupID + ProjectID
```